# Unable to Autoplay Embedded Audio in PowerPoint File

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint

I have some Microsoft PowerPoint files which were sent to me and contain what should be automatic playback audio and slide transitions. For some reason I cannot get the audio to auto-play. I can play back the audio fine in preview/edit mode but it will not autoplay the audio despite checking the audio playback options are set to "start automatically". Occasionally (not every slide) it will start playing the first 1 second of audio and then cut out.

The PPT and audio were created on a Mac and I am on Windows 10 but the audio was recorded directly into PPT so it should be compatible. Furthermore, I have renamed a file to ZIP and opened up the Media directory and specifically determined the files are M4A AAC encoded files which should be Windows PPT compatible.

If I export the media on each slide and then re-import it the playback works fine (though the audio speaker graphic on the slide does change slightly making me think there is something going on there). However, this will be a large number of presentations/slides and manually exporting and re-importing the audio is not an option.

I explored creating a macro to do the export and re-import of the audio but it appears there is no currently supported VBA method to export embedded audio from slides..there is some indication it used to be supported as the Export method of the SoundFormat object but that appears to have been deprecated, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8779992/8666467

Any ideas? I can create a sample presentation with a few slides demonstrating the issue if that would be helpful. Just let me know where to post it for easy accessibility.